# Cooling shape question

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, physics, estimation

There is a cube in a room, experiencing heat transfer through all of its faces. The initial temperature of the cube is $20$ degrees and the temperature of the environment is $5$ degrees. I need to work out the temperature of the cube after $600$ seconds.

The constant coefficients of the faces are: $0.001$ through $4$ of the faces, $0.005$ through $1$ of them, and $0.0015$ through the other.

I started by forming a differential equation, where $T$ is the temperature of the cube:

$$\frac{dT}{dt} = - ( 0.005(T-5)+0.0015(T-5) + 4 (0.001(T-5)))$$

I think the answer is either around $10.25$ degrees or $17.9$ degrees as I created a programme to estimate it using Euqler's Rule. Does anyone have a programme to verify which answer seems most reasonable or can solve it and tell me which seems most reasonable ?

Comment: Is the cube initially at 20 degrees and the room at 5 degrees or the other way around? The whole cube will not have a single temperature on all faces unless it has cooled (or been raised) to the temperature of the room.

Comment: @Paul The cube has initial temperature $20$ degrees and the temperature of the environment is $5$ degrees.

Comment: So if the cube is ever going to have a single temperature it will be 5 degrees. The temperature of the cube between t = 0 and t = 'large' will be complex and different for each face.

Comment: You could try assuming an average conductivity from the 6 faces and threat it as a single variable cooling problem

Comment: @Paul I understand your point. I have only been told to work out the relationship between $T$ and $t$ though where $T$ is the temperature of the cube

Comment: @Paul As in, from the differential equation that I posted in my question, that is what I need to estimate

Comment: @Paul: Like e.g., when a hot copper cube from outside on a hot day transferred into a refrigerator.

Answer (score 0):

We could lump the constants together
$$ \frac{T-5}{20-5}=e^{ -\frac14 ( 0.0005+ 0.0015+4* 0.001)} $$

Comment: So adding the constants together would be the correct way of solving ?

Comment: I am not sure it is the correct way. Or on what basis  the original  convection law or other heat transfer modes  was derived by Newton. I imagined it was proposed on the basis of measured temperature fall as an  asymptotic decline.